# For loop is returning promises in the wrong order

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm calling a function a certain amount of times to fetch individual src attributes from an array of lists. The src attributes are coming back in the wrong order. I've tried using setTimeout but that returns an array of nulls and my own pause function just returns the same order of list just a certain amount of milliseconds later.

The function is called here:

```
  myLoopingFunction: function(links) {
    var pause = function sleep(milliseconds) {
      var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
      while (currentTime + milliseconds >= new Date().getTime()) {
      }
    }
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var promise = deferred.promise;
    var src = [];
    for (var i = 0;i < links.length;i++) {
      getSrc(links[i]).then(function(response) {
        src.push(response)
      });
    }
    deferred.resolve(src);
    return deferred.promise;
  }
```

EDIT:
This is the function:

```
     var getSrc = function(links) {
      return $q.all(links.map(function(link){
         return $http.get(link.Address);
     })).then(function(results){
         var src = results.map(function(result){
           var tmp = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument();
           tmp.body.innerHTML = result.data;
           var video = $(tmp.body.children).find('#definitionblock iframe');
           var video_src = $(video[0]).attr("src");
           return video_src;
         });
     })
  };
```

It's being called here:

```
      bslLogin.getSrc($scope.links).then(function(response) {
        $scope.videos = response;
        console.log($scope.videos);
      })
```

It's now returning undefined. I can see via console.logs that the chain of functions is producing the right result till the end where it returns undefined. It doesn't even recognise the return value as an array.

Comment: the for loop isn't returning promises. The callback is inserting the result in an array, but the callbacks are unlikely to run in order, because they're asynchronous.

Comment: Also, you're resolving your deferred way too early.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [`$q.all()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all) to get the results of your "http-promises" in the expected order. In your code the http calls are running asynchronous (concurrently) and the callback handlers, which add responses to the array, too.

This could be a solution with an array of promises (be careful, the code is untested):

```
$q.all(links.map(function(link){
    return $http.get(link.Address);
})).then(function(results){
    var src = results.map(function(result){
        var tmp = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument();
        tmp.body.innerHTML = response.data;
        var video = $(tmp.body.children).find('#definitionblock iframe');
        var video_src = $(video[0]).attr("src");
        console.log(video_src);
        return video_src;
    });
    return src;
})
```

Comment: This is Angular. Use `$q.all`

Comment: So i've pretty much taken out the looping function and just used getSrc. When I return $q.all i get an undefined result. `bslLogin.getSrc($scope.links).then(function(response) {
            $scope.videos = response;
            console.log($scope.videos);
          })` but if I don't return $q.all i get an error saying "cannot read property 'then' of undefined"

Comment: You have to create a promise for every link, that is the reason why I used the `Array::map` function (`links.map`) which maps every link to a http-promise: `$http.get(link.Address)`. The result is an array of promises and used as a parameter to `$q.all`. So the list of promises is transformed to ONE promise. If you use your `getSrc` function, the call `$http.get(link.Address).then` resolves the http-promises immediately - or is it that what you changed? It is hard to get your problem without the to see the code you use... Did you try the code in my answer?

Comment: I've edited getSrc in my post to show what it looks like now. That in conjunction with the method call in my first post is whats returning undefined. I've put in console logs and it looks like the chain of functions is working fine until the final return.

Comment: `tmp.body.innerHTML = response.data;` ... response is undefined, the parameter you want to use is `result`. So you could try `tmp.body.innerHTML = result.data;` But another thing... it should be possible to find the element in the result directly: `$(result).find('#definitionblock iframe');` could work, if not, you could add the result (or response) to your question.

Comment: @Meiko Yes I changed that in getSrc with the $q.all change. I can see via console.logs that they're all defined and do work up to the end point then just return undefined. I've updated the initial post with the latest code.

Comment: In 'getSrc' we have to return the array src in the anonymous function. I added the return statement in my answer.